# Magento2: Aws CloudFront Product Image cache issue

Tags: magento2, cloudfront-cdn

I have integrated Aws CloudFront in our Magento 2 site.

Product image not showing in our site.

1. How to solve product cache issue.
2. When I used CloudFront CDN URL. All images stored in the S3 bucket
   so why is creating a folder again in the media folder.